# Enabling Cors in local IIS

Tags: jquery, ajax, iis, asp.net-web-api, cors

I've tried following the steps from Microsoft

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api

I committed the codes I created in GitHub link below

https://github.com/RGatchalian/StackOverflowQuestions/tree/master/ASPNET/EnablingCors

Just to explain, Front-end folder is the call from Javascript to the WebApi and TestingCors folder is the WebApi. I'm currently running this in my local IIS. I deployed the WebApi using Web Deployment and just put the Front-end into inetpub/wwwroot/. And it actually works when both are in localhost

[image]

The problem that I have is when I'm developing and wanted to test, I'm getting errors.
[image]

The only workaround is to use Chrome with disable-web-security. And it works. I tried changing the WebApiConfig.cs and web.config with what I got from Google but it's still not working.

[image]

UPDATE
Here's the code

```
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <authorization>     
        <allow users="*" />   
    </authorization> 
    <!-- <compilation targetFramework="4.5.2" /> -->
    <!-- <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" /> -->
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <cors enabled="true" >
        <add origin="*"  />           
    </cors>
  </system.webServer>
```

This is the error I'm getting when I put allowCredetials

[image]

when I remove allowCredentials it works but the user doesn't get detected.
[image]

Comment: https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/iis-cors-module

Comment: Thanks @LexLi. It looks like it's not working in Windows Authentication Mode. At first, it wasn't working until I disabled Windows Authentication and Enabled Anonymous Authentication. I saw some blogs where allowCredentials="true" needs to be added but that didn't work either.

Comment: Not sure if you wrote this. https://blog.lextudio.com/how-to-handle-cors-preflight-requests-in-asp-net-mvc-web-api-with-windows-authentication-f19814cbb558

Do you have an example for this?

Answer (score 1):

I can reprodcue this issue on my side.

[image]

The reason for web browser returning this error is you opened index.htm from physical path and CORS get blocked.

Please open it from either IIS or IIS express. Then you need to modify your attribute to

```
 [EnableCors(origins: "http://www.myclient.com", headers: "*", methods: "*", SupportsCredentials = true)]
```

Finally you will see CORS when you call api from http://www.myclient.com

[image]

[image]

Comment: @ReydanGatchalian What error message did you get when you host the client ajax in IIS?

Comment: Basically the WebApi could be implemented on a Windows Authentication or not. The one I'm currently testing is the one with Windows Authentication. The problem I have is when I add allowCredentials="true" on either on the <cors> tag or <add origin="*"> it fails please see UPDATE  on the post

Answer (score 1):

its related to CORS issue. Cross Origin Resource sharing, to resolve you need to enable the cors.
We can enable CORS three ways:

1. Global level
2. controller level
3. or specific method level

if you want to enable on method level you can decorate EnableCors attribute, check below code:
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
you can write specific urls in origin, header also you canset specific header that you are going to pass and method name as where you need to apply.
I am adding * for all generic(any one can access).

I hope it would be helpful for you to resolve your issue.

Comment: I have done this but didn't work. I've tried all levels.